# What does InvokeVerb("{:}") do, and how do I do it in C#?

Tags: c#, vbscript

Hello can someone please help me to find an alternative to this code in C# wpf.

```vb
With WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    With .Namespace(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile))
        .ParseName(objFSO.GetFileName(objFile)).InvokeVerb("{:}")
    End With
End With
```

I can't find an equivalent in C# for `InvokeVerb("{:}")`. Can someone tell me at least what these lines are doing?

Thanks anyway :D

Comment: Hard to say without a little more code for context.  Perhaps related to [pinning an item to the taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720595/pin-program-to-taskbar-using-ps-in-windows-10/38880235#38880235)?

Comment: @ashleedawg wow your Google-fu is impressive! It's gotta be it!

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am trying to do. The others lines I understand how it works and how to do it in C# but not these 5 lines

Comment: Well then, that code is pinning `objFile` to the task bar

Comment: I just want to know how to do an invokeverb("{:}") in C#

Comment: lol, I've been a longtime beleiver that Google skill is more important than Coding skill, and should be the centre of Coding 101.  In my opinion, the secret to coding-related Google-fu is always choosing **`Tools`→ `Vertbatim`** (or using this link for the same result **`https://www.google.ca/?tbs=li:1`**)

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872103/pin-lnk-file-to-windows-7-taskbar-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Rufus L Thank you I will try with that :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's be related to **pinning an item to the taskbar** in Windows 10.

---

### More Information:

- [Pin program to taskbar using PS in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720595/pin-program-to-taskbar-using-ps-in-windows-10/38880235#38880235)
- [Pin *.lnk file to Windows 7 Taskbar using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872103/pin-lnk-file-to-windows-7-taskbar-using-c-sharp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [How to programatically pin and unpin my program to Windows7 taskbar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/a1660523-fdeb-4307-af4c-2cb188b882ae/how-to-programatically-pin-and-unpin-my-program-to-windows7-taskbar?forum=windowsuidevelopment)

Comment: Congrats on your 6K! Next stop, 10K!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon -Maybe a *couple* stops in between here and there  but **thanks**! :-) That's what I get for answer a question for a language I've never touched in my life, about a VBA command I've never used...